# Using mysql_* functions with a mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was wondering if the older mysql_* functions provided with php will work with a mysqli connection.

Comment: I doubt so. What prevents you from testing? And what's the reason of such unusual question?

Answer (score 2):

No, the mysql_* functions were used only with the mysql driver.

There are new functions created for using with mysqli which you can read more about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

The new method is object oriented instead of the old functional style.

Comment: mysqli also provides function aliases to the OO interface. Under the hood both mysqli and mysql use the new mysqlnd, which is a driver written in native php instead of just binding to libmysql.

Comment: Ah, good to know, I hadn't seen those.  The basic answer is still correct though, you cannot use the old functions with the new connection type.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql extension uses [resources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) [for the link identifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.resources.php):

> There are two resource types used in the MySQL module. The first one is the link identifier for a database connection, the second a resource which holds the result of a query.

[MySQLi does not provide any resources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.resources.php):

> This extension has no resource types defined.

Consequently, when doing

```
$link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'secret', 'test');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 'it works' FROM dual", $link);
```

you will get

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given

and `$result` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

No, they won't, they're two entirely difference resources.

Unless you're trying to do a drop-in replacement of a MySQL connection with a MySQLIi connection, there's not much need for you to worry about this, unless you can't stand writing the `i` every time :-P

Remember though that you can still connect to newer MySQL databases with the `mysql_*` commands.